# Integral substitution, convert integral

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I need to find a good substitution to convert integral $\int \frac{1}{t^2+a^2}dt$ to integral $\int \frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$.
Can anybody please help me? I don't know the method to use to I approach it.
I know that: $\int \frac{dx}{x^2+a^2}=\frac{1}{a}arctg\frac{x}{a}+c$.
The problem is to get rid of the $a$.

Comment: What have you tried??? What are your thoughts?

Comment: I tried to do it by some formulas but I couldnt find a good one for it.

Comment: Could you edit the question to add which formulas you tried? The reason I ask is because the more context (such as your solution attempt for this question) the more helpful it will be to both you and anybody else who may stumble upon this question. Maybe one of the formulas you tried **is** helpful, and I could show you how. Someone may look in the future and wonder how to do the same thing, and it will help them to see a natural progression of thought on the problem. Not just "problem statement" then "answer"

Comment: I really dont know how to get rid of just the a and all leave the same.

Comment: Essentially - you are asking how to derive the fact that ${\int \frac{1}{x^2 + a^2}dx=\frac{1}{a}\arctan\left(\frac{x}{a}\right) + c}$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$t^2 + a^2 = a^2((t/a)^2 + 1)$

so $x=t/a$ is a sensible substitution, with $a\ dx = dt$

$\int \frac{1}{t^2+a^2}dt = \int \frac{1}{a^2(x^2+1)}a\ dx = \frac1a\int\frac{1}{x^2+1}dx$

Can you take it from there?

Comment: Thanks a lot! :)